# How to remove redundant punctuations (keep only the first one) in text?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all redundant punctuations (as well as space) of English text in string type and only keep the first punctuation from each 'group' of punctuations/space.

Punctuations: `string.punctuation` :  `` !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ``

Example:

`I like this city very much!!! :\\ $%& It is because it contains many good food..! $ % Unfortunately,,, I need to go back home tomorrow. .`

Should be:

`I like this city very much! It is because it contains many good food. Unfortunately, I need to go back home tomorrow.`

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, wow. That's not as straightforward, as it may look. You need to translate English punctuation rules to code, so it could remove all excessive punctuation marks. There should definitely be a library available for that job.

Comment: Probably doable if you assume "keep only the first one" will always be correct, as in your example. Otherwise it's not a well defined problem

Comment: @Lala Please don't edit the post to add additional questions. If you have another question, you may ask a new one. Remember to include your attempts to solve the problem. For more guidance, please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
r'(?<=[^!.,>$%&-][!.,>$%&-])[!.,>$%& -]+(?<! )'
```

(For readability I have reduced the collection of special characters as shown.)

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/7TMMmX/2/)

If the string were:

```
I like this city very much!!! $%& It is because it contains many good food..! $ % Unfortunately,,, I need to go back home tomorrow. . ->
```

the following string would be returned:

```
I like this city very much! It is because it contains many good food. Unfortunately, I need to go back home tomorrow.
```

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=           : begin a positive lookbehind
  [^!.,>$%&-]  : match any character other than those shown in the
                 character class 
  [!.,>$%&-]   : match any character in the character class
)              : end positive lookbehind
[!.,>$%& -]+   : match any character in the character class
(?<! )         : negative lookbehind matches a space
```

Note that

```
[!.,>$%& -]+(?<! )
```

could be replaced with:

```
[!.,>$%& -]*[!.,>$%&-]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following pattern to match two or more punctuation/space characters:

```regex
[!\"#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]{2,}
```

Then, you can define a function to replace the match with the first character of the match in addition to a space character if the original contained at least one.

My knowledge of python isn't very good but the code should look something like this:

```
import re

def my_replace(match):
    match = match.group()
    return match[0] + (" " if " " in match else "")

regex = r"[!\"#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]{2,}"

test_str = "I like this city very much!!! :\\\\ $%& It is because it contains many good food..! $ % Unfortunately,,, I need to go back home tomorrow. ."

result = re.sub(regex, my_replace, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

**Output:**

```
I like this city very much! It is because it contains many good food. Unfortunately, I need to go back home tomorrow.
```

[**Try it online**](https://rextester.com/KUEU11229).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we can fix the string by removing punctuation *only* (without removing spaces), and that the first punctuation is correct (as per title), then this should be solvable.

The regexp `r'([A-Za-z\s]+[,])[,\s]*'` matches a group of characters and whitespace, followed by a punctuation mark (for conciseness, a comma). The second group matches all unnecessary whitespace and punctuation. So something like

```
m = re.findall("[A-Za-z\s]+[,])[,\s]*", test_string)
' '.join(m)
```

should work, assuming you replace comma with an appropriate list of punctuation symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This script removes all duplicated punctuation and deals with the special case of extra spaces within the duplicated punctuation clusters.

```
mstr = "I like this city very much!!! :\\ $%& It is because it contains many good food..! $ % Unfortunately,,, I need to go back home tomorrow. ."
newstr = []
for x in mstr:
    if x in string.punctuation:
        if pctindex == 0:
            newstr.append(x)
            pctindex += 1
    else:
        if (x == ' ') and pctindex > 0:
            pass
        else:
           newstr.append(x) 
           pctindex = 0
print(''.join(newstr))
```

it yields:

```
I like this city very much!It is because it contains many good food.Unfortunately,I need to go back home tomorrow.
```